# Javascript event when changing/focusing tab/window

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there an event handler for focusing or blurring a tab or window in jQuery?
blur() and focus() don't seem to work on window.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/6ckFZ/

jQuery blur event on `window` works for me.

```
$(window).blur(function() {
  alert('Handler for .blur() called.');
});
```

Comment: oh, for some reason i used live. It doesn't seem to work using this, but thanks for your answer. Thought I had tried it like that.

Answer (score 7):

You can bind the window's blur function, so jQuery would be `$(window).blur(handler)`

You can even test it on this page real quick, pop
`javascript: window.onblur = function() { alert("Blur"); };` into your action bar and alt tab.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `onkeydown` if people will be typing into a box, or `onfocus` for the initial click into the window. See the examples below.

```
<input type="text" onfocus="myFunction()">
```

or

```
<input type="text" onkeydown="myFunction()">
```