# Use window.open to a tab in the background (not switch focus)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pdf

I'm using the following code to open a new tab on click of a PDF download.

The problem is the new tab becomes the main tab often before the PDF loads.

**How can I make the view stay on the current window** (PDF) and open the new tab but not switch to it?

Note: In Chrome and Opera they understand the HTML5 download tag so the PDF simply downloads and the current window redirects - All good! So this is only a problem on IE & Firefox.

```
<h2 style="text-align: center;"><a href="http://cdn2.hubspot.net/hub/155045/file-847580737-pdf/Stepping_into_a_new_age_of_marketing_with_CRM_FINAL_APPROVED.pdf" onclick="casestudiesopen()" download><strong>Click here to download your eBook</strong></a></h2>

<script>
function casestudiesopen() {
    window.open("http://www.workbooks.com/case-studies");
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'll advise you to read this Stackoverflow answer, which is, in a way, quite similar to yours (the purpose anyway) :

[Javascript disable switches current tab functionality in browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18455752/javascript-disable-switches-current-tab-functionality-in-browser)

JS/JQuery is indeed very powerful but also have its limits. Imagine a web page always requesting and keeping focus once you've opened it. I think you would be really annoyed, among other things.

That's why browsers prevent those kind of actions. Common browsers at least. Meaning, there's no way to prevent a browser like Firefox, Chrome, IE & Co. to focus a table since it depend of user's parameters.

You'll have to find a way to workaround your problem. I can propose this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5656849/javascript-event-when-changing-focusing-tab-window) since it seems to have worked for the other guy.